# Differentiating the limits of a definite integral - multivariable

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

How would I go about finding the following:
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \left( \int_x^{x-2y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}  e^{-z^2/2t} dz \right) $$

Comment: What is $t$? Is it a constant? This problem is not very interesting b/c nowhere in the integrand does $x$ or $y$ appear. So you would just break up the integral into two, and apply FTC part 1 or you may need to check the conditions on the function but if the order of differentiation does not matter (Clairaut's Theorem), then do $y$ first. The integral disappears. $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\int_x^{x-2y} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2t}} dz\right)\right]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \left( \int_x^{x-2y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}  e^{-z^2/2t} dz \right) & = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \left( \int_x^{x-2y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}  e^{-z^2/2t} dz  \right) \right) \\
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}  e^{-(x-2y)^2/2t}  \right] \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x-2y) + \left[  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}  e^{-(x)^2/2t}  \right] \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x) \right) \\
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{-2}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}  e^{-(x-2y)^2/2t}\right) \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{2}  e^{-(x-2y)^2/2t}(x-2y)}{t\sqrt{\pi t}}
\end{align*}